# How to truncate the decimal values in sql server 2000

Tags: sql-server

I have a expression:

```
Select (2345789 * 39.456) / 100
```

The output is `925554.5078400`.

I would like to display `925554.50` i.e. 2 values after decimal.

If I use round

```
Select round((2345789 * 39.456)/100, 1)
```

the output is `925554.5000000`. But I want exactly 2 digits after the decimal. How to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stating the obvious, but 925554.5000000 and 925554.50 are the same number.

If you want to *display* that number with two decimal places then that is an issue for your UI code, not your database.

Having said that, if you *must* do this in the database itself then try something like:

```
-- 1 decimal place
SELECT CAST(ROUND(@yourNumber, 1, 1) AS DECIMAL(18, 1))

-- 2 decimal places
SELECT CAST(ROUND(@yourNumber, 2, 1) AS DECIMAL(18, 2))

-- 3 decimal places
SELECT CAST(ROUND(@yourNumber, 3, 1) AS DECIMAL(18, 3))

-- 4 decimal places
SELECT CAST(ROUND(@yourNumber, 4, 1) AS DECIMAL(18, 4))
```

Comment: No ,it should not get round off. If I give SELECT CAST(((2345789 * 39.456)/100) as decimal(18,3)), I would expect to get the output as 

925554.507 instead of 925554.508.

And if I use SELECT CAST(ROUND((2345789 * 39.456) / 100, 1) AS DECIMAL(18, 2)), the output is 925554.500.

And also, may be the example that I gave, here it is coming as .50, but if it comes as say1.23498567, then I need 1.23 as opposed to 1.20.

Hope you understand.

Comment: @pewned_123: I edited just before your comment appeared. Should be fixed now, I think.

Comment: Even the same problem is with FLOOR. Though you changed from ROUND to FLOOR. Value should not be rounded off.

I want 925554.500 not 925554.508

Comment: @pewned_123: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you give a list of expected inputs and outputs?

Comment: Sure, for example say the input is 925554.5078400.

If I want to display only 2 decimal values, it will be 925554.5.
If I want to display only 2 decimal values, it will be 925554.50.
If I want to display only 3 decimal values, it will be 925554.507.
If I want to display only 4 decimal values, it will be 925554.5078.

As you can see, itis not  rounded off anywhere

Comment: Sorry, the statement will be If I want to display only 1 decimal values, it will be 925554.5.

Instead I typed  If I want to display only 2 decimal values, it will be 925554.5

Answer (score 1):

I have solution also use truncate value

```
Select (2345789 * 39.456)/100  result-925554.5078400
select cast (ROUND((2345789 * 39.456)/100 ,2,1)as decimal(18,2)) result-925554.50
select cast (ROUND((2345789 * 39.456)/100 ,3,2)as decimal(18,3)) result-925554.507
select cast (ROUND((2345789 * 39.456)/100 ,4,3)as decimal(18,4)) result-925554.5078
```

ok. I hope you understand from this.

Answer (score 0):

Try (not tested):

```
SELECT CAST(number as decimal(18,2))
```

Comment: If I give SELECT CAST(((2345789 * 39.456)/100) as decimal(18,2)), it is wroking fine but it is rounding off too.

I am getting 925554.51 instead of 925554.50

Answer (score 0):

See:

```
select ROUND(12345.67890,-4) --result: 10000.00000
select ROUND(12345.67890,-3) --result: 12000.00000
select ROUND(12345.67890,-2) --result: 12300.00000
select ROUND(12345.67890,-1) --result: 12350.00000
select ROUND(12345.67890,0)  --result: 12346.00000
select ROUND(12345.67890,1)  --result: 12345.70000
select ROUND(12345.67890,2)  --result: 12345.68000
select ROUND(12345.67890,3)  --result: 12345.67900
select ROUND(12345.67890,4)  --result: 12345.67890

select ROUND(12345.67890,-4,1) --result: 10000.00000
select ROUND(12345.67890,-3,1) --result: 12000.00000
select ROUND(12345.67890,-2,1) --result: 12300.00000
select ROUND(12345.67890,-1,1) --result: 12340.00000
select ROUND(12345.67890,0,1)  --result: 12345.00000
select ROUND(12345.67890,1,1)  --result: 12345.60000
select ROUND(12345.67890,2,1)  --result: 12345.67000
select ROUND(12345.67890,3,1)  --result: 12345.67800
select ROUND(12345.67890,4,1)  --result: 12345.67890
```

You can use:

```
select ROUND(12345.67890,1)  --result: 12345.70000
```

Or:

```
select ROUND(12345.67890,1,0)  --result: 12345.70000
```

**Note:** ROUND ( numeric_expression , length [ ,function ] )

*numeric_expression*

Is an expression of the exact numeric or approximate numeric data type category, except for the bit data type.

*length*

Is the precision to which numeric_expression is to be rounded. length must be an expression of type tinyint, smallint, or int. When length is a positive number, numeric_expression is rounded to the number of decimal positions specified by length. When length is a negative number, numeric_expression is rounded on the left side of the decimal point, as specified by length.

*function*

Is the type of operation to perform. function must be tinyint, smallint, or int. When function is omitted or has a value of 0 (default), numeric_expression is rounded. When a value other than 0 is specified, numeric_expression is truncated.

*Reference: http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms175003.aspx*